# json inputting data from sql database while loop

Tags: php, sql, database, json, while-loop

I have a code of json but I don't know how to input the while loop.

I have the code edited the contents but i don't have an idea how to while loop a json because I'm getting distracted by the , next line it means next picture right tried to add one it works but don't know how to insert while on it here's the link of the example.

[link](http://demo1.krablekod.ru/agile_carousel/examples/agile_carousel_multiple_slides_visible_example.html)

```
> agile_carousel_data.php
>     <?php
>     include_once('includes/dbConnect.php');
>     
>     
>     ?> <?php
>     
>     $query = mysql_query("select * from persons order by rand()");
>     
>     while ($test = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
>         
>     }
>     
>     
>     
>     ?> [ {
>                "content": "<div class='slide_inner'><a class='photo_link' href='#'><img class='photo' src='banner_bike.jpg'
> alt='Bike'></a><a
>          class='caption' href='#'>Sample Carousel Pic Goes Here And The Best
>          Part is that...</a></div>",
>                "content_button": "<div class='thumb'><img src='f2_thumb.jpg' alt='bike is nice'></div><p>Agile Carousel Place
> Holder</p>" }, {
>                "content": "<div class='slide_inner'><a class='photo_link' href='#'><img class='photo' src='banner_paint.jpg'
> alt='Paint'></a><a
>          class='caption' href='#'>Sample Carousel Pic Goes Here And The Best
>          Part is that...</a></div>",
>                "content_button": "<div class='thumb'><img src='f2_thumb.jpg' alt='bike is nice'></div><p>Agile Carousel Place
> Holder</p>" }, {
>                "content": "<div class='slide_inner'><a class='photo_link' href='#'><img class='photo' src='banner_bike.jpg'
> alt='Bike'></a><a
>          class='caption' href='#'>Sample Carousel Pic Goes Here And The Best
>          Part is that...</a></div>",
>                "content_button": "<div class='thumb'><img src='f2_thumb.jpg' alt='bike is nice'></div><p>Agile Carousel Place
> Holder</p>" }, {
>                "content": "<div class='slide_inner'><a class='photo_link' href='#'><img class='photo' src='banner_paint.jpg'
> alt='Paint'></a><a
>          class='caption' href='#'>Sample Carousel Pic Goes Here And The Best
>          Part is that...</a></div>",
>                "content_button": "<div class='thumb'><img src='f2_thumb.jpg' alt='bike is nice'></div><p>Agile Carousel Place
> Holder</p>" }, {
>                "content": "<div class='slide_inner'><a class='photo_link' href='#'><img class='photo' src='banner_bike.jpg'
> alt='Bike'></a><a
>          class='caption' href='#'>Sample Carousel Pic Goes Here And The Best
>          Part is that...</a></div>",
>                "content_button": "<div class='thumb'><img src='f2_thumb.jpg' alt='bike is nice'></div><p>Agile Carousel Place
> Holder</p>" }, {
>                "content": "<div class='slide_inner'><a class='photo_link' href='#'><img class='photo' src='banner_paint.jpg'
> alt='Paint'></a><a
>          class='caption' href='#'>Sample Carousel Pic Goes Here And The Best
>          Part is that...</a></div>",
>                "content_button": "<div class='thumb'><img src='f2_thumb.jpg' alt='bike is nice'></div><p>Agile Carousel Place
> Holder</p>" }, {
>                "content": "<div class='slide_inner'><a class='photo_link' href='#'><img class='photo' src='Penguins.jpg'
> alt='Tunnel'></a><a
>          class='caption' href='#'>Sample Carousel Pic Goes Here And The Best
>          Part is that...</a></div>",
>                "content_button": "<div class='thumb'><img src='f2_thumb.jpg' alt='bike is nice'></div><p>Agile Carousel Place
> Holder</p>" }, {
>                "content": "<div class='slide_inner'><a class='photo_link' href='#'><img class='photo' src='Penguins.jpg'
> alt='Tunnel'></a><a
>          class='caption' href='#'>Sample Carousel Pic Goes Here And The Best
>          Part is that...</a></div>",
>                "content_button": "<div class='thumb'><img src='f2_thumb.jpg' alt='bike is nice'></div><p>Agile Carousel Place
> Holder</p>" }
>          
>          ]
```

here's my code for the while loop and query

```
$query=mysql_query("select * from persons  order by date desc LIMIT 0,10 ");

> <img height=200 width=200 src=' upload/". $test['Image'] ."'/> <a href
> ='profile.php?PersonID=$id'> ".$test['LastName'].", ". $test['FirstName']." ". $test['MiddleName']."</a>
```

and here's my script file for calling the code

```
> agile_carousel_multiple_slides_visible_example.html
> 
> <script>
> 
>     $.getJSON("agile_carousel_data.php", function (data) {
> 
>         $("#multiple_slides_visible").agile_carousel({
>             carousel_data: data,
>             carousel_outer_height: 230,
>             carousel_height      : 200,
>             slide_height         : 200,
>             carousel_outer_width : 480,
>             slide_width          : 260,
>             number_slides_visible: 3,
>             transition_time      : 330,
>             control_set_1: "previous_button,next_button",
>             control_set_2: "group_numbered_buttons",
>             persistent_content: "<p class='persistent_content'>Agile Carousel Example: Multiple Slides Visible</p>"
>         });
> 
>     })
> 
>  </script>
```

tried this code but won't output anything

```
> `<?php include_once('includes/dbConnect.php'); $data = array(); while
> ($test = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { $data[]['content'] = "<div
> class='slide_inner'><a class='photo_link' href='#'><img class='photo'
> src='{$test['image']}' alt='Bike'></a><a class='caption'
> href='#'>Sample Carousel Pic Goes Here And The Best Part is
> that...</a></div>" $data[]['content_button'] = "<div
> class='thumb'><img src='{$test['thumb']}' alt='bike is
> nice'></div><p>Agile Carousel Place Holder</p>" } echo
> json_encode($data); ?>
```

`

Comment: What does your PHP have to do with JSON, in this case?

Comment: I am not clear on what you are asking.

Comment: i have an image name on my database try to take a look on the link :D i'm using this php json layout. so what i'm asking is how to put my while loop command to replace the fields that i got from this site here's the original so i'm going to call datas from my database and display it like the link i given . [link](http://demo1.krablekod.ru/agile_carousel/examples/agile_carousel_multiple_slides_visible_example.html)

Answer (score 0):

Client side, your loop should look like:

```
//first assign the entire Array to var whatever
for(var i in whatever){
  var eachObject = whatever[i];
  for(var n in eachObject){
    var eachObjectValue = eachOject[n];
  }
}
```

If you just want to access, say the 2nd value of the 3rd Object in your `whatever` Array it would look like:

```
whatever[2].content_button or whatever[2]['content_button'];
```

Comment: hmm didn't quite get your example sorry i really don't have idea on json i'm still learning

Comment: You are processing an Array that contains a bunch of JavaScript Objects, which are really more like Associative Arrays that can be accessed with a dot if their properties don't have a space in them. If your property was `"content button" : "value here"` then you could not use the dot.

Comment: yes that's the one messing my head the , thing and { }. thanks but i got the flow but the application of code using for loop i didn't get it sorry just a beginner